# Persistent background task Django + Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, background, cron

I have a persistent background process currently running as a standalone python script on my `ubuntu` server, managed by `supervisor`. However, I am migrating to `Heroku` and wonder if anyone have any experiences setting up the same kind of environment.

The specifications of the script;

1. Fetch information from external API
2. Do calculations on the data
3. Store the data to the database
4. If the script used less than 5 seconds, sleep for the remaining time, else run again

I could run a cronjob every 5 seconds, but from time to time step 1-3 can take up to a full hour.
Any tips?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is create a worker process. Simply define a command line script so that you can call it easily, then in your `Procfile`, add a new worker entry like so:

```
# Procfile
web: python manage.py runserver # example
worker: python manage.py start_cronjob # command to run your background process
```

Once you've got this defined in your `Procfile`, go ahead and push your app to Heroku, then scale up a worker process:

```
$ heroku scale worker=1
```

This will launch a single worker process.

To view the logs and ensure things are working as expected, you can say:

```
$ heroku logs --tail --ps worker
```

Comment: I actually found this out the other day, and I can't believe it's not high up in the documentation. Heroku support team kept telling me to schedule jobs and/or use a redisqueue. Thanks alot, buddy.